# Continuous function that is $0$ for a point in an open set and 1 outside that set

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm reading a proof and got stuck here:

> Since $x_0 \in \overline{U} \setminus A$ and $A$ is closed in
>   $\overline{U}$, there exists a continuous function $f: \overline{U} \to [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ and $f(A) \subset \{1\}$.

$\overline{S}$ denotes the closure of the set $S$ in the whole space $X$.

Is there some standard theorem in topology that allows us to conclude this?

Comment: What sort of space is $X$ (or, since only $\overline{U}$ is relevant, $\overline{U}$)? It's the definition of a $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ space (or completely regular space, whatever is the weaker one in your preferred nomenclature) if we let $x_0$ and $A$ be arbitrary (with $A$ closed in and $x_0 \notin A$).

Comment: $X$ is locally compact and $\overline{U}$ is compact. The theorem being proved here is "Every locally compact space is $T_{3 \frac{1}{2}}$".

Comment: Does "locally compact" include the Hausdorff property in this course/book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $X$ is Hausdorff in addition to being locally compact. Now, $\overline U$ is a topological subspace of a Hausdorff space and hence Hausdorff itself with respect to its relative topology. Since $\overline U$ is also compact in addition to being Hausdorff, it is normal (see a proof [here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Hausdorff_implies_normal)), that is, $T_4$. Since $\{x_0\}$ and $A$ are disjoint closed subsets of $\overline U$, the result now follows from [Urysohn’s lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma).